# Connction of IBM-db with Google Colab

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, db2, google-colaboratory

Here is the problem, i got the following error msg from system, anybody could help me solve it out?
here is my input code

```
# Enter your Db2 credentials in the connection string below
# Recall you created Service Credentials in Part III of the first lab of the course in Week 1
# i.e. from the uri field in the Service Credentials copy everything after db2:// (but remove the double quote at the end)
# for example, if your credentials are as in the screenshot above, you would write:
# %sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@hostname:port/BLUDB?security=SSL
# Note the ibm_db_sa:// prefix instead of db2://
# This is because JupyterLab's ipython-sql extension uses sqlalchemy (a python SQL toolkit)
# which in turn uses IBM's sqlalchemy dialect: ibm_db_sa

%sql ibm_db_sa://xxxxxx77:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZR@ba99a9e6-d59e-4883-8fc0-d6a8c9f7a08f.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud:31321/bludb？security=SSL
```

The usename and password is correct since i use IBM-db API connection method it was fine and success connect to IBM cloud database

```
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

Comment: This can be reference at  to the IBM Data Analyst Certificate Course 6 Week 4 Lab 2

Comment: Did you check both ibm_db_sa and ibm_db are installed?

Comment: Your question shows a space after the databasename and question-mark before security=SSL.  Remove that space. Verify the ibm_db_sa module is installed (!pip show ibm_db_sa).

Comment: yes , i install ibm_db_sa and ibm_db

Comment: ya i try both question mark and semicolon after bludb and no space as well it still did not work

Comment: Please try the end of the connection string exactly like this `bludb;security=SSL;`  (notice the semicolon both before and after the property setting).

Answer (score 0):

here are two image i try on google colab, install the ibm_db and other requirement,
[image]
here is the image show that it did not go through with it
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

bludb;security=SSL; with the two semi colons worked. i had same issues with co-lab

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).